# How to add Ember-Bootstrap to an EmberJS project created via Yeoman

Tags: ember.js, yeoman

I've started working on an EmberJS application and used Yeoman to generate the skeleton structure. Now, I'd like to add Ember-Bootstrap to my project but am having trouble doing so. I downloaded the latest version from GitHub and unzipped it but I'm not sure what to include.

I see several .js files in the packages/ember-bootstrap/lib folder. Do I need to include all of these? If so, then in which order should I include them?

Someone mentioned in another answer that you needed to add it to the "assets" folder but I don't have one of these.

Does installing Ember-Bootstrap require having a Rails project? I'm not familiar with Rails so please forgive for the newbie questions.

Thanks.

Comment: You can get the built version of bootstrap from the example in github. All the js files you see in the project must be built into a single js file and a css file which you place anywhere in your project and reference it to your html. You can also fork the bootstrap and build it yourself

Comment: Thanks for that. I actually figured out how to build the project. I'm not a Ruby guy so it took me a while to get Rake and Gem working. In any case the build produced a "dist" folder and in there I see the following 4 files: ember-bootstrap-spade.js, ember-bootstrap.js, ember-bootstrap.min.js, and ember-bootstrap.prod.js

Comment: Obviously, the one I'm interested in is ember-bootstap.js or ember-bootstrap.min.js but I was wondering why I could not find the Bootstrap.Button component in any of the files generated. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

I found a great project that supports Bootstrap 3.0 with many components,

you can find it here:
https://github.com/ember-addons/bootstrap-for-ember

you can see all components alive:

http://ember-addons.github.io/bootstrap-for-ember

GoodLuck.

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer the question posed by the OP.